# JPA and PostqreSQL: long string persistence

Tags: postgresql, jpa

Can anybody tell me how to persist long text using JPA (I use PostgreSQL)?

Here's the way I defined a very long string in my class:

```
@Lob
private String  body;
```

However, this produces a field of type *charactervarying(255)* in the database.

Furthermore, I've tried to use @Column annotation:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String  body;
```

But everything in vain.

I would be gratefull for a helpfull comment on this problem.

Comment: I was doing the first thing, and I got an OID, LO in postgresql, true nightmare

Answer (score 20):

```
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
```

is indeed the way to do it. Perhaps you have to regenerate your DDL?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that @Column annotation is completely ignored.

Comment: Dear Jonathan,  I tired the above suggested fix but I am getting error. Your help will be apreciable. Please help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094410/hibernate-abstractmethoderror-setcharacterstreamiljava-io-readerjv?noredirect=1#comment39048566_25094410

Answer (score 17):

I had the same case today.
Just

```
@Lob
private String  body;
```

should create a db column of typ "text" (PostgreSQL - variable unlimited length) but the table should be regenerated.

Comment: This one should be the correct approach, the other solutions are giving me: ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"

Comment: for a database independent solution, this must be the correct choice

Answer (score 12):

This is a very old post, but since it has lots of views, and I had a similar question even today, I guess it's worth a simple answer.

My solution was similar, but I found that I needed the `LONGTEXT` column instead:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="LONGTEXT")
private String body;
```

And yes, you do have to regenerate it.  I'm using Play! and I had to restart my app.

Comment: What was your intention to use LONGTEXT instead of TEXT? The reason is missing.

Answer (score 1):

JPA, Postgresql
You can use:

```
@Column(length = 2000)
    private String template;
```

it generates:

```
template character varying(2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the validation annotations:

```
@Size(max=xxx)
```

That would also serve as a validation constraint of course.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but I added
@Column(length = 1024)

on top of the getter and it works.