# Hibernate Error while persisting TEXT datatype

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, exception, text

Using hibernate and mysql 5.5, I am trying to persist String value in TEXT type column of database table.

Tired to set String value in the mentioned column and tried to persist the data.But i am getting following exception. I have generated Entity class using Netbeans 8.0. 

**Exception:-**

```
FATAL:   JSF1073: javax.faces.FacesException caught during processing of INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=/addNewCategory.xhtml @30,151 actionListener="#{categoryBean.addCategoryAction}": java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V
FATAL:   /addNewCategory.xhtml @30,151 actionListener="#{categoryBean.addCategoryAction}": java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V
javax.faces.FacesException: /addNewCategory.xhtml @30,151 actionListener="#{categoryBean.addCategoryAction}": java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:89)
```

**CREATE SQL:-**

```
 CREATE TABLE `oc_category_description` (
      `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `description` text NOT NULL,
      `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `meta_keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`language_id`),
      KEY `name` (`name`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

**EntityClass**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "oc_category_description")
@XmlRootElement
public class OcCategoryDescription implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

     public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
    //Constructors, setters, getters, equals and hashcode
}
```

Before raising question I went through following links which were of very little help.

- [JPA: how do I persist a String into a database field, type MYSQL Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868096/jpa-how-do-i-persist-a-string-into-a-database-field-type-mysql-text)
- [JPA and PostqreSQL: long string persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870927/jpa-and-postqresql-long-string-persistence)
- [Issue persisting long strings with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112667/issue-persisting-long-strings-with-hibernate)

- I also tried to persist data by removing `@Lob`, it saving data as "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.BlobProxy@11e84b60"
- I tried `using @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")` instead of `@Lob`, again its giving same result. "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.BlobProxy@11e84b60"
- I tried `@Type(type="text")`instead of `@Lob`, again its giving same result. "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.BlobProxy@11e84b60"

Comment: Try removing Lob and Basic annotations from the entity class

Comment: Tried. Its saving like "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.BlobProxy@11e84b60".

Comment: What do you mean by "Its saving like "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.BlobProxy@11e84b60"? Are you unable to get the entity back from the DB?

Comment: Yes, On Reading OR SELECT query  I am getting "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.BlobProxy@11e84b60". As am saving String, I would I like to persist the same as String rather than Object.

Comment: try adding length to the Column annotation Column(length="1000"). How do you retrieve the entity from the DB?

Comment: I am planning to retrieve using Named Query. @NamedQuery(name = "OcCategoryDescription.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM OcCategoryDescription o"). TRIED @Column(name = "description",columnDefinition = "TEXT",length = 1000). Same Result.

Comment: post the code how do you retrieve the entity

Comment: remove the `@Lob` and `@Size` annotations, and use `@Type(type="text")` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> remove the @Lob and @Size annotations, and use @Type(type="text")
>   instead

WORKED. Thanks @Maurice and @Funtik