# Hibernate annotation, Mysql TEXT column, always create varchar

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have an entity class with a String property that I want to map to a TEXT column.
I use java 8, mysql 5.7.18 on ubuntu and hibernate 5.2.6

I used `@Column(name='x', columndefinition='text not null')` (accordind to this post [What properties does @Column columnDefinition make redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078681/what-properties-does-column-columndefinition-make-redundant)), after that, I use `@Type` after `@Column` according to this post [Hibernate Error while persisting TEXT datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094410/hibernate-error-while-persisting-text-datatype), but always my column created as `varchar(255)`

are there problem in my code and scenario? or there are any configurations

Comment: Can you try this @Column(name="x",columnDefinition = "TEXT")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple OR BIG mistake!

I've used `@column` annotation before set method, instead of **get** method

Answer (score 3):

if you want this property  mapped as a text into your table use @Lob annotation top level of your property that's define as a String in entity class.